# Anaconda warning conda.common.logic:get_sat_solver_cls(278)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda

```
(base) C:\Users>conda update --all
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: / WARNING conda.common.logic:get_sat_solver_cls(278): Could not run SAT solver through interface 'pycosat'.
failed
```

**CondaDependencyError**:

> Cannot run solver. No functioning SAT implementations available.

Now I can't update, how should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Download and install Miniconda to a location X different from your current installation path Y. The python version Z should be the same as the broken installation. Then run the command

```
X\Scripts\conda.exe install -p Y python=Z conda
```

to heal the broken installation. Additional details are available [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7714#issuecomment-417553149).